# How to solve "OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix) in cvCheckTrainData" error while using emeocv?

Tags: opencv

I am learning emeocv with opencv from https://www.mkompf.com/cplus/emeocv.html. I pretty much followed it accurately. My programming environment is :

> Ubuntu 14.04
>
> opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1

In the tutorial page mentioned above, when i reach 'main program' section

> sudo ./emeocv -i images -l

this command throws an error

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix)
> in cvCheckTrainData, file
> /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp,
> line 857 terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'cv::Exception'   what():
> /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:857:
> error: (-5) train data must be floating-point matrix in function
> cvCheckTrainData

and I am unable to proceed further.

I don't even know where this file "/build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp" exists.

How can i resolve this error, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you started training mode before but didn't train any data.
Simply delete the empty trainctr.yml and start again with real data.

[Source](https://github.com/skaringa/emeocv/issues/2)